# In LibSpotify, how can I get track details gives its link

Tags: android, spotify

I am developing a Spotify app on Android based on the LibSpotify library. In my application, I store a list of track links. I now want to retrieve the details of all these tracks, by first getting a reference to each track object:

```
sp_link *link = sp_link_create_from_string(trackUrl);
sp_track *track = sp_link_as_track(link);
```

And then for example getting their album names by:

```
sp_album_name(sp_track_album(track));
```

However, "sp_track_album(track)" returns NULL since the track is not loaded. How can I efficiently access the meta data of these tracks?

I considered loading each track for playing via "sp_session_player_load(sp_session *session, sp_track *track);" but this is extremely inefficient considering I want to access the details of a long list of tracks.

Can I maybe use the function "sp_search_create" with some specific format of the query parameter? I tried for example the following but without succes:

```
sp_search_create(session, "link:\"spotify:track:3XyMPyuWwHcGMvXeJY6Qt0\"", 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SP_SEARCH_STANDARD, &search_complete_callback, (void*)0);
```

Please help me, thanks!